# Specify particular caldender dates only for selection

Tags: cognito-forms

I run a class every thursday, id like my visitors to be able book on future thursdays only.  Is there a day to do this via the date field?  So it only allows them to select a future thursday

Answer (score 0):

On your date field, enable Show Custom Error, When, and use this calculation.

```
=(DateField.DayOfWeek != "Thursday") or (DateField < DateTime.Today)
```

Remember to add a custom error message.